# Write a Trigger For changing subscription start date to the 1st of every month and end date to last date of the month on term object

Tags: trigger

I have written code for the change subscription start date and end date to the start of the month and end of the month respectively, but this code doest't change any functionality in the salesforce. I've been stuck here for days.

where OrderApi__Renewal__c = term object and start and end date fields

```java
trigger SubscriptionTermDateChange on OrderApi__Renewal__c (before insert) {
    List<OrderApi__Renewal__c> orl=new List<OrderApi__Renewal__c>();

    for(OrderApi__Renewal__c ord:Trigger.New) {
        OrderApi__Renewal__c sub = new OrderApi__Renewal__c();    
        Date d1 = Date.today();
        Date startDate = d1.toStartOfMonth();
        ord.OrderApi__Term_Start_Date__c = startDate;
        Date lastDate = startDate.addMonths(1).addDays(-1);
        ord.OrderApi__Term_End_Date__c = lastDate; 
        orl.add(sub);               
    }  
    insert orl;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to update the same record which is getting created?

Comment: both existing and new records

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the start and end date fields of the OrderApi__Renewal__c record which is getting inserted, there is no need to create a new record of the same object. You just have to update the field values accordingly.

Please use below:

```
trigger SubscriptionTermDateChange on OrderApi__Renewal__c (before insert) {

    for(OrderApi__Renewal__c ord : Trigger.New) { 
        Date d1=Date.today(); 
        Date startDate=d1.toStartOfMonth(); 
        ord.OrderApi__Term_Start_Date__c=startDate; 
        date lastDate=startDate.addMonths(1).addDays(-1); 
        ord.OrderApi__Term_End_Date__c=lastDate; 
    }
}
```

Also, note that this can be easily done in **Record Triggered Flow** with no code. Please visit [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com) to learn more about Flows.

Comment: Thank you very much sir it worked